# Two sets of constructor parameters in a scala class

Tags: class, scala, constructor

What does this code do? Why is there two sets of constructor parameters?

```
class A(val x: Int)(val y: Int)
```

I can initialize an object and use both fields:

```
val a = new A(5)(7)
println(a.x + ", " + a.y)
```

If I make it a case class, I can match only by the first set of parameters.

```
case class A(x: Int)(y: Int)
val a = A(5)(7)
a match {
  A(x) => println(x)
}
```

It's not possible to create 3 sets of parameters. It doesn't compile. So what is the meaning of the two sets of constructor parameters?

Comment: It's not something I made up. I found this construction in the scala swing library: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/swing/scala/swing/event/MouseEvent.scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (see section 5.3), the second set of parameters is dedicated to implicit parameters. Dividing the parameters in two sets allow you to define only non-implicit paameter and let the other be contextually defined.

It is quite strange actually that the compiler accpet non-implicit parameters in the second set.

Comment: Thanks. If I add the _implicit_ keyword into the second set, it starts to be implicit, but it's not implicitly implicit without the _implicit_ keyword.

Anyway, the scala specification does not allow non-implicit parameters in the second set.

Comment: Well... this section of the spec seems very strange: the example given right below the grammar does not seem to correspond to the gramar. And "class Test (a:Int)(b:Int)(c:Int)" is a valid class definition.

Comment: @PeWu +1 for having the phrase "it's not implicitly implicit without the implicit keyword" :)